# Updating .net aspx website in live

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web

net website with webform and Vb

My question is

I update a file in aspx.vb (code behind) in Dev

can  I upload just the aspx.vb file to prod server or
 I have  to rebuild all the web site and upload it to the prod server

Answer (score 1):

If your application type is website than you can copy & replace that individual file (aspx.vb) on PROD. If it's webapplication than you should build it first & deploy.

Comment: need i restart the server for that

Comment: @samit No in case of website you don't need to. Your changes will be reflected in the subsequent request.